# How do I import weather data from meteostat and display it as a heatmap?

Tags: folium, meteostat

I am trying to make a temperature layer on a map however i am having some trouble trying to get this layer to work. I want it so that the data is displayed on the map as a heat map not as a graph like the examples i have looked up online.

I have tried a similar thing to what i have done with the population aspect of the map layer:

```
    def access_map(self, latitude, longitude, layer='Population, Temperature, Landmarks'):
        # Create a map using Folium
        map = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=6)

        if layer == "Population":
            # Connect to the database
            conn = sqlite3.connect("world_cities_population.db")
            cur = conn.cursor()

            # Query the database for the data
            cur.execute("SELECT city, latitude, longitude, population FROM cities")
            data = cur.fetchall()

            # Prepare the data for the heat map
            heat_data = [[float(lat), float(lon), float(pop)] for city, lat, lon, pop in data]

            # Add population data layer to the map
            population_layer = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Population Layer")

            # Add the heat map layer to the map
            heat_map = HeatMap(heat_data)
            heat_map.add_to(population_layer)

            # Add the population layer to the map
            population_layer.add_to(map)

            # Get the population values
            populations = [pop for _, _, _, pop in data]

            # Define the color scale for the legend
            max_population = max(populations)
            min_population = min(populations)
            color_scale = folium.LinearColormap(['green', 'yellow', 'red'], vmin=min_population, vmax=max_population)

            # Add markers to the map
            for name, latitude, longitude, population in data:
                marker = folium.CircleMarker(
                    location=[latitude, longitude],
                    radius = 3,
                    popup=f"City: {name}<br>Population: {population}",
                    color = '#9d54f0',
                    fill = True,
                    fill_color = '#9d54f0',
                    tooltip=name
                )
                marker.add_to(population_layer)

            # Create the legend
            legend_html = '''
            <div style="position: fixed; 
                        bottom: 50px; left: 50px; width: 150px; height: 120px; 
                        border:2px solid grey; z-index:9999; font-size:14px;
                        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
                        ">
                <p><span style="background: #84aaec; padding: 5px;"></span> Very Low Population </p>
                <p><span style="background: green; padding: 5px;"></span> Low Population</p>
                <p><span style="background: yellow; padding: 5px;"></span> Medium Population</p>
                <p><span style="background: red; padding: 5px;"></span> High Population</p>
            </div>
            '''

However this has not worked. Anyone have any tips?
```